# Create an empty promise

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I have a function in a chain of promises that may or may not do something.  E.g.

```
  getYear().then(function(results){
    if(results.is1999) return party();
    else return Q.fcall(function(){/*do nothing here*/});
  }).then(sleep)
```

Where `getYear`, `party`, and `sleep` all return promises.  Is there a more concise way to write the else statement?  That is, do nothing, but still return a chainable promise?

Comment: `return party` or `return party()`?

Comment: I has assumed that party was just a promise value rather than a function which returned a promise.

I had also assumed that it didn't matter either way as this was just code to demonstrate the example.  I'm now forced to assume you're genuinely creating a program that throws a party, but only if it's 1999.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is production code and totally serious.  Incidentally, thanks for your very thorough response.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes.  `Q(value)` returns a promise for the `value` (it also unwraps the value if `value` is a promise).

```
  getYear().then(function(results){
    if(results.is1999) return party();
    else return Q(undefined);
  }).then(sleep)
```

Alternatively, you can get the exact same semantics by just not returning anything:

```
  getYear().then(function(results){
    if(results.is1999) return party();
  }).then(sleep)
```

If what you wanted was a promise that's never resolved, your best bet would be

```
  getYear().then(function(results){
    if(results.is1999) return party();
    else return Q.promise(function () {});
  }).then(sleep)
```

What you could do is re-use the same promise:

```
  var stop = Q.promise(function () {});
  getYear().then(function(results){
    if(results.is1999) return party();
    else return stop
  }).then(sleep)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a promise that's never resolved"? Is there any advantage to that over having a promise that returns the value (say, `results`)?

Comment: @Patrick Promises can be in one of three states: Pending, Fulfilled & Rejected. You can have a promise remain in the "Pending" state forever. This is what I mean by "a promise that is never resolved". I would say that in general it is an anti-pattern, but it might be useful if you want to prevent all logic after a given function from ever happening. It allows you, in effect, to skip all the success handlers and all the failure handlers further down the chain.  It is probably best avoided though.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem like a bad idea. What is it in the example that causes the promise to never be fulfilled? Because the final `.then(sleep)` returns a promise that never gets assigned to anything? (And thus can't be `.then`'ed or `.done`'ed?)